# Fulltext search remove index retry?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

There is no statuscode return when doing index().remove(..)  ? but there status code return for index().add(..). There is no requirement to do retry if the remove(..) fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Index.remove()` should throw an exception if there is a problem.  Specifically (from the `remove` method documentation):

```
"Raises:
  RemoveError: If one or more documents failed to remove or
    number removed did not match requested.
  ValueError: If document_ids is not a string or iterable of valid document
    identifiers or number of document ids is larger than
    _MAXIMUM_DOCS_PER_REQUEST."
```

Comment: for java how to catch the exception ?

Comment: Sorry, missed that your question was for Java.  In that case, you would catch RemoveException (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/search/Index#remove(java.lang.String...)